# Particles look different in render mode

Tags: materials, particles, hair

I'm trying to create cotton fuzz on a sleeve. To do so, I'm using a particle system with simple children. I'm kinking these hairs in a spiral shape. This is what the hairs look like in the solid viewer:
[image]

And this is what they look like in the rendered viewer:
[image]

Why am I getting these ball shapes instead of thin hairs? Thanks to anyone who can help :)